# $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] Apache/Xampp forbidden access

Tags: php, apache, permissions, xampp

I am using an Xampp/Apache server on localhost.

I am trying to use an action on a form which posts to "register.php".

```
<form method="post" action= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["register.php"]);?>">
```

I get a 403 error "Access Forbidden".

In the url it states:

```
<br%20/><b>Notice</b>:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20register.php%20in%20<b>C:/xampp/htdocs/2001/create_account.php</b>%20on%20line%20<b>45</b><br%20/>
```

(Error on line 45 which is the line of code above).

The file this code is in is a php file, create_account.php

I have tried changing apache httpd.conf permissions, no changes. I have tried finding the solution elsewhere but no luck with a fix.

Comment: Just use `<form method="post" action="register.php">`, there is no need for the `htmlspecialchars` or `$_SERVER` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read the manual page for $_SERVER carefully
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

you may find action="register.php" is all you will need

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you've tried to call for an undefined key which array `$_SERVER` doesn't have and therefor you've got an error.

`$_SERVER` is a php superglobal and it's form is an array. Arrays can be indexed, associative or mutlidimensional. Associative arrays use keys to accesses values `('key' => 'value')`. Example of an associative array:

```
$person=array('Name' => 'John', 'Last name' => 'Spencer', 'Age' => 22);
```

In order to get John's last name you'd first need to specify the array in which all of the information is being held (`$person`) and then request certain information from that array via key (`['Last name']`). Example of such request:

```
$lastName=$person['Last name'];
```

If you already know the page you'd like to accesses you should type it in HTML as plain text (`method="register.php"`), there's no need for any php functionality in doing this. Function `htmlspecialchars()` also isn't necessary since you are the one typing and there's no need to sanitize your own input.

Better than plain text however would be to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` which returns relative path to the page you're currently on. This way is better than previous since if at some point you were to rename your file you wouldn't have to change to your form's method value unlike in previous example.

Finally if you're not leaving the page you're currently on you could also place an empty string as method (`method=""`).

Recommended for further read:

- [php.net's documentation on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [w3school's documentation on arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)